# In Microsoft Power Automate, what is the proper use of the character, '\r' in a schema?

Tags: power-automate

When working with the functionality of reading data from a cvs file into a dataflow, it is required, I believe, to use a schema.  It seems to me that this schema has to be designed to accommodate the end of a line in the data.  What is the proper way to do this?

First of all, It seems that all schemas start like this:

```
> {
>     "type": "array",
>     "items": {
>         "type": "object",
>         "properties": {
>             "Title": {
>                 "type": [
>                     "string",
>                     "null"
>                 ]
>             },
```

After this, the schema lists the individual columns.  Let's say that in our case, we only have three columns, "Name", "Profession" and "Profession-2".  In order to recognize  that we have reached the end of the line as we read data, the \r character should be used. I assume this is how it should be done:

```
>            "Name": {
>                 "type": [
>                     "string",
>                     "null"
>                 ]
>             },
>             "Profession": {
>                 "type": [
>                     "string",
>                     "null"
>                 ]
>             },
>             "Profession-2\r": {
>                 "type": [
>                     "string",
>                     "null"
>                 ]
>             }
```

Finally, there is the "required" block.

```
>         "required": [
>            "Name",
>             "Profession",
>             "Profession-2\r",
>         ]
```

What are your thoughts?  Did I get this right?  Is there some sort of documented explanations somewhere outlining the proper use of the /r character?